# Inegrity Error While Saving Queries From View

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am getting Integrity Error. The data is entering database. Then after it is giving error. Why this is happening Can any tell me how to do it

> IntegrityError at /trustyrequest/update/4/
>
> (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'")

```
class TrustyRequestUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    template_name = "trustyrequest/update.html"
    model = TrustyRequest
    form_class = TrustyRequestForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('trustyrequest_list')

    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        
        if form.cleaned_data['status'] == 'Accepted':
            print('PK: ', form.instance.id)
            random_password = User.objects.make_random_password() # generate password here 
            user = User(
                first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'], 
                last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'], 
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                phone_number=form.cleaned_data['phone_number'], 
            )
            user.set_password(random_password)
            user.save()

        elif form.cleaned_data['status'] == 'Pending':
            print('Pending')
            print('PK: ', form.instance.id)
            
        elif form.cleaned_data['status'] == 'Rejected':
            print('Rejected')
            print('PK: ', form.instance.id)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Is there a good way to do above code. I am using AbstractBaseUser for User Model

Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import UserManager

from apps.roles.models import Role


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=True)
    
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Returns the short name for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        '''
        Sends an email to this User.
        '''
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "user"
```

This is my Managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Form.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import TrustyRequest

class TrustyRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrustyRequest
        fields = [
            'name', 
            'address', 
            'first_name', 
            'last_name', 
            'email', 
            'phone_number',
            'status',
        ]
```

Comment: You need to show the full message - what is  the integrity error? Plus you'll have to show the definitions of the form and model.

Comment: see i have added the code

Comment: Please add the code of `TrustyRequest` model and `TrustyRequestForm` form.

Comment: Added See it please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an update view to create a new user. When using an update view, it is expected that you already have the user in the database (you have the pk of 4 in the url, no?).

You should use a get() in the update view to retrieve the user as the syntax you are using is creating a new user every update. The error indicates that you are trying to duplicate a unique field - i.e the new user has the same email as an existing user

In form_valid() change the user creation to:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=form.instance.id)
user.first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']
user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name]
...
..
user.save()
```

Comment: I am getting Same `IntegrityError at /trustyrequest/trustyrequest/update/1/
(1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'")
`

Comment: but the data i am updating is of `TrustyRequest` and i am create new user in `User`

Comment: Are  creating a new user or updating an existing one? Your URL says update. The view you are using is an update view. Your form is creating a new user, not updating an existing user. That's why it complains that you already have a user with that email address.

Comment: Yeah i am creating new user while updating the status of `TrustyRequest`

Comment: Well change the email address when you fill in the form and it should work. You already have a user with that email address in the database.